# Ruby on Rails undefined method `email'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am running into some problems with a rails app I'm developing..  I am using the simple_form gem from https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form and after running `rails server` I am seeing the following error

```
undefined method `email' for #<User:0x007f7c9888c950>
```

Extracted source (around line #7):

```
<%= simple_form_for User.create, :input_html => { :class => 'form-horizontal hide', :id => 'dataWithinSignIn'} do |f| %>
 <div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
#7 <%= f.input :email, :id => 'inputEmail', :placeholder => 'Email' %>
  </div>
  <div class="controls">
   <%= f.input :password, :id => 'inputPassword', :placeholder => 'Password' %>
```

My source code is at https://bitbucket.org/jasonriddle/stubmoney on branch `test-repo` I've searched for hours on the internet for answers but I haven't found an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the only migration I see in your code:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.references :user
      # Same as saying
      # t.integer :user_id (Foreign Key Column)
      # t.string  :imageable_type (Type Column)
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

There's no email column there and it doesn't look you've set up your users table correctly anyway since all it has is a reference to user and the default timestamps.

I would run `rake db:rollback` to drop the users table and then edit the migration to look like this before migrating again:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :password # or :encrypted_password
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Also, you would typically name your password column something like `encrypted_password` and then have a virtual attribute named `password` in your user model. The virtual attribute is what's used in forms. (like in your example simple_form code)

Comment: Thank you! I am a newbie but I am quickly learning how awesome ruby on rails is!

Answer (score 0):

simply run the migration `rails g migration add_email_to_users email` this should fix the problem as the email attribute is missing

Then run `rake db:migrate`